# Load my own PDF document into Syncfusion PDF viewer using Javascript

Tags: javascript, syncfusion

I recently started using syncfusion and I am experiencing some problems with it. I am trying to load my own PDF document into the PDF Viewer but I every time I change the documentPath to my own it does not work. I am suspecting that it has to do something with the service Url.

This is what I have so far:

```
<div id="pdfViewer" style="height: 640px; width: 100%;"></div>

<script>    
    // Render the PDF viewer control
    var viewer = new ej.pdfviewer.PdfViewer({
        documentPath: "PDF_Succinctly.pdf",
        serviceUrl: 'https://ej2services.syncfusion.com/production/web-services/api/pdfviewer'
    });
    ej.pdfviewer.PdfViewer.Inject(ej.pdfviewer.Toolbar, ej.pdfviewer.Magnification, ej.pdfviewer.BookmarkView, ej.pdfviewer.ThumbnailView, ej.pdfviewer.TextSelection, ej.pdfviewer.TextSearch, ej.pdfviewer.Print, ej.pdfviewer.Navigation, ej.pdfviewer.LinkAnnotation, ej.pdfviewer.Annotation, ej.pdfviewer.FormFields);
    viewer.appendTo('#pdfViewer');
</script>
```

Please assist me how I can change the documentPath to my own. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The document name provided in the documentPath API should be available in the location mentioned in the PdfViewerController.GetDocumentPath() in Web service project. We have only limited document in our online web service so the reported issue occurs. We can resolve this by using local web service project. We can also provide the PDF document base64 string in documentPath API . We have shared the JavaScript sample and the Web service project in the below link,

JavaScript: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/index_(2)-248954391 
Web Service Project: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/PDFViewerWebService_(4)610597217

Please refer to the below link to create PDF Viewer web service project in ASP.NET Core,

Web service .Net Core 3.0 :https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/11063/how-to-create-the-pdf-viewer-web-service-application-in-net-core-3-0-and-above-version

Web service .Net Core 2.0: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/10346/how-to-create-pdf-viewer-web-service-application-in-asp-net-core

Kindly run the Web service project first and provide that URL to the serviceURL property of the PDF Viewer.

Please try it and revert us if you have any concerns on this.

Regards,
Akshaya